# crash/minidump when adding WFS layer

Tags: qgis, wfs, minidump

When I try to add a WFS-layer in QGIS, it crashed automatically. It generates a .dmp file, which I opened in Notepad++, but I don't know where to look for the actual cause of the crash.

Tried various WFS-links, all crash. Tried various options (change CRS, zooming to certain area, "only request features overlapping the view extent", using different titles of the same WFS-server... etc...

Some of the WFS links I've used:

```
https://services.geodan.nl/public/data/org/gws/MBIZ4280LEEF/MBIZ4280LEEF/wfs?
https://geodata.nationaalgeoregister.nl/rwsgeluidskaarten/wfs?
https://geodata.nationaalgeoregister.nl/bag/wfs?
```

Any ideas on what the problem might be?

Windows 10, 64-bit
QGIS Desktop 2.18.8

Comment: I tried the first link provided and can't reproduce your error. The WFS loads just fine.: Windows 10  64bit QGIS 2.14.15. So is it an option to "downgrade" QGIS?

Comment: Thanks for the "downgrade"-tip. I also have version 2.16 installed and it worked with this older version.

Answer (score 1):

This doesn't solve the problem itself but allows you to continue your work. It could be a bug.

**Workaround:**

- If you can choose which version you use, try Version 2.14 or 2.16.
- You can load the WFS with the functions QGIS provides.
- It seems to be a bug in version 2.18.8